# WooCommerce Inclusive Tax for International Orders

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woothemes

I use the API to set the prices on my site and its configured to accept inclusive prices.

I have set up the standard rate for the VAT for my country.

I now need to allow a neighbouring country to be able to purchase from my store. However, I want them to buy at the inclusive price but with no VAT.

I tried adding the country to the standard rates at 0% but that just deducts the local VAT from the price. So if the price is $15 normally, now will show as $12. I need the price to be the same as the local inclusive price but with 0% VAT.

So if I sell something for $15, the VAT may be $3 locally. On my local orders this what will show. Now if my foreign customer wants to buy something, it need to still show it at $15 but the VAT is 0%.

I just can't find a way to get the system configured that way.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer

add_filter( 'woocommerce_adjust_non_base_location_prices', '__return_false' );